# Disable hide of a Presentation (Secondary Screen)

Tags: android, service, presentation

I´m working on a project which should show a little presentation on a secondary display (API 4.2). Till now all is working fine. But if I close the application I can´t prevent presentation from being closed. I would like to create a application which is starting a background service which is initializing the presentation. So that the user just see a notification icon in the statusbar but the service is streaming the content to the secondary display.

Any ideas if this could be realized? I tried it with the backgroundservice but don´t know which context I should use. Tried it with

```
getApplicationContext()
```

but then I just get a exception:

```
Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

If I use a static method like `getAppContext()` (I know such a ugly hack) it will show the presentation but will also hide it if i close the application.

Any ideas?

Comment: Great question! I'm trying to to do the same with no success!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a Service that uses the Context.createDisplayContext(Display) to obtain a new Window manager for your secondary display - this is how Presentation works

take a look at this link as an example: 
http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/com/android/server/LoadAverageService.java.htm

In onCreate() instead of getting the WindowManagerImpl:

```
public void onCreate(){
    ... 
    WindowManagerImpl wm = (WindowManagerImpl)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.addView(mView, params); 
}
```

call a method like this:

```
private void addView(WindowManager.LayoutParams params){
    DisplayManager dm = (DisplayManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(DISPLAY_SERVICE);
    if (dm != null){
        Display dispArray[] = dm.getDisplays(); 

        if (dispArray.length>0){
            Context displayContext = getApplicationContext().createDisplayContext(dispArray[1]);
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)displayContext.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            wm.addView(mView, params);
        }
    }
}
```

Your view will be added to the secondary display and since this runs by a Service, your activity running on the main display is not paused

Comment: What are you using for your `type` in your `WindowManager.LayoutParams`? `TYPE_APPLICATION` and kin blow up with errors involving a missing `token`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560241/how-to-set-up-a-window-on-an-external-display-from-a-service for more details. Thanks!

Comment: Link update: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/eclair-release/services/java/com/android/server/LoadAverageService.java

Answer (score 5):

> Any ideas if this could be realized?

Since `Presentation` is a subclass of `Dialog`, your `Presentation` can only be visible when you have the activity hosting it in the foreground.

---

**UPDATE**

icarmel's answer works, though it is missing some details. I have a `PresentationService` now in [my CWAC-Presentation library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-presentation) that offers a complete working implementation of the technique. To answer my question in my comment on icarmel's answer, you use `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` in the `WindowManager.LayoutParams`, which in turn requires the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission (unfortunately).

Comment: Okay thank you. But do you have any idea how i can show the presentation if the screen is off? It´s really strange that the presentation dismiss if i turn off the display. Strange use case if I´m sitting on the couch streaming some videos with mirracast and the tv fade to black because the display of the smartphone turn off...

Comment: @mkl: "But do you have any idea how i can show the presentation if the screen is off?" -- I'll be a bit surprised if this is possible, and I certainly do not know how it can be done. "Strange use case if I´m sitting on the couch streaming some videos with mirracast and the tv fade to black because the display of the smartphone turn off" -- keep the screen on, using `android:keepScreenOn="true"`.

Comment: Yeah i thought there must be a solution like that (example: youtube). But thats ugly :( Thought google would create a more powerful API. I think I have to do it like you mentioned and try to decrease the display brightness and show a black rectangle which will save power on AMOLED displays. 
Thank you!

Comment: @mkl: There's no question that making `Presentation` extend `Dialog` has its side effects, and there may be tricks here of which I am unaware.

Comment: @CommonsWare I seem to be able to use a service to add a view to a secondary display (based on your `PresentationService` class) without `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` in the layout params and without the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission. I've tested both on API 17 (emulator using secondary display developer option) and API 19 (actual device using Chromecast mirroring). Any ideas why this is working without the permission? Is the permission really needed?

Comment: @ashughes: It definitely was needed when I wrote `PresentationService`. I couldn't get it to work with HDMI connections otherwise. It's possible that it is not needed under some scenarios. I'll run more tests when I get a chance. Thanks!