# How to Set Up a Window on an External Display from a Service?

Tags: android

Android added `Presentation` in API Level 17 (Android 4.2) to support displaying content on an external `Display`, such as as TV or monitor connected via HDMI, MHL, Miracast, or SlimPort. However, `Presentation` extends `Dialog`, and so it is only usable from an `Activity`.

And, as far as I knew, that was the end of the story.

However, [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16307314/115145) hints at a possible way to use an external `Display` from a `Service`, by means of `createDisplayContext()` and `WindowManager` created from that `Context`. Then, the `addView()` method on that `WindowManager` should render the `View` onto the indicated `Display`. If this can be made to work, it really opens the door for interesting uses of external displays, such as playing a video on a TV while being able to use unrelated apps (e.g., a Web browser) on the device's own touchscreen.

However, that answer glosses over a key detail: how to set up the `WindowManager.LayoutParams` for the `addView()` call. In particular, there are a dizzying array of possible `TYPE_` values for the `type` field. I have crashed in two attempts, though with different messages:

- `TYPE_APPLICATION` results in `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application`
- `TYPE_APPLICATION_MEDIA` results in `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?`

For example, here is my `WindowManager.LayoutParams` for the second scenario above:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams p=
    new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                   0,
                                   0,
                                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_MEDIA,
                                   0, PixelFormat.OPAQUE);
```

Reading through [the docs for `type`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#type) suggest that none of the `TYPE_APPLICATION` will be correct, as I do not have a `token`. Moreover, the point behind this exercise is to *not* have a `token`, as least as far as I can tell, as the `Service` is supposed to run independently from any UI.

If you look at the source to `Presentation`, it defers the `WindowManager` work to `Dialog`, which uses `com.android.internal.policy.PolicyManager`, which quickly dead-ends in an `IPolicy`. An SDK app does not have access to `PolicyManager`, anyway.

Has anyone gotten the `createDisplayContext()` approach to work from a `Service`? If so, what did you use for the `type` (or, more generally, for the `WindowManager.LayoutParams` in general)? Bonus points for a solution that does not involve some icky permission. :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT type used conjunctly with the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission should work.

It makes sense that launching a dialog from a service 
 requires "icky" permissions, it basically allows you to draw over other apps :)

Comment: Well, it doesn't blow up, which is an improvement. But I do not get my content (e.g., `ImageView`) showing on the external display, either. The external display reacts, by not showing the mirroring, but it does not show what I add to the `WindowManager` tied to the display `Context`. The LogCat contents are unremarkable. So, I think you're on the right track, but there may be more that I need to configure on the `WindowManager.LayoutParams` to get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I don't quite know what I did, but it's working now, at least on a limited basis. Now to work on extending it. Thanks!

Comment: I suppose your View was in fact displayed, but with some issues.

Instead of creating yourself a DisplayContext and adding a view, you may try to directly display a Presentation-derived class (still with setting `dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);`)

This works on my Asus Fonepad Note FHD 6 (Android 4.2.2): http://ph0b.com/uploads/videoOnOverlayDisplay.jpg

Comment: FYI, and FWIW, I just updated [my CWAC-Presentation library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-presentation) that adds a `PresentationService` that implements the approach that you described. Thanks again!

Comment: @CommonsWare ...Your Presentation Library is really a good reference..Thanks..!!

Comment: I posted a comment on another question about this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148275/disable-hide-of-a-presentation-secondary-screen/16148317#comment38598743_16148317) about how I don't seem to need the `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` layout param type and `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

I am showing a Presentation on the external screen of a flip phone. It is running from a service that starts in the background after boot. Showing the presentation looks like this:

```
   try {
        val selectedRoute =
            (this.getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_ROUTER_SERVICE) as MediaRouter).getSelectedRoute(1)
        val presentationDisplay = selectedRoute?.presentationDisplay
        val mPresentation =
            PresentationScreen(this, presentationDisplay)
        Log.i("StatusBar", "Showing presentation on display: $presentationDisplay")
        mPresentation.requestWindowFeature(1)
        mPresentation.show()
        Log.i("StatusBar", "Showing presentation.")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.w(
            "StatusBar",
            "Couldn't show presentation!  Display was removed in the meantime.",
            e
        )
    }
```