# How to launch foreground service on secondary screen

Tags: android, android-service, screen, display, foreground

I use the following codes to launch the activity on secondary screen:

```
ActivityOptions opts = ActivityOptions.makeBasic();
opts.setLaunchDisplayId(mExternalDisplayId);
context.startActivity(intent, opts.toBundle());
```

It works well.
But when I launch the foreground service inside the activity, using the following codes:

```
startForegroundService(Intent)
```

The foreground service will launch on main screen and then display the videoview. Does anyone know how to launch the foreground service on secondary screen?

**[UPDATE]**
How to display the videoview when launching a foreground service?

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
VideoView view = new VideoView(this);
try {
    wm.addView(view, getWindowLayoutParams(false));
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "", e);
}
```

See [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148275/disable-hide-of-a-presentation-secondary-screen) for more details. I use the above source codes to play video when service creates.

**[SOLVED]**
I found use getApplicationContext() to instead of this(context) likes that

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
```

The screen which view shows is the same as application.

Comment: service originally is not designed to *run on the screen* at all. Show how you do that.

Comment: "The foreground service will launch on main screen" -- services are not shown on any screen. "and then display the videoview" -- you might consider editing your question to show the code that is trying to do this.

Comment: Thank you. I found the root cause.